# Cache performance of Python array (not list)

Tags: python, arrays, cpu-cache

I understand that Python's `array` provided by the array module stores consecutively the actual values (not pointers). Hence I would expect that, when elements of such an array are read in order, CPU cache would play a role.

Thus I would expect that Code A below should be faster than Code B (the difference between the two is in the order of reading the elements).

Code A:

```py
import array
import time
arr = array.array('l', range(100000000))
sum = 0

begin = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10000):
        sum += arr[i * 10000 + j]
print(sum)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

Code B:

```py
import array
import time
arr = array.array('l', range(100000000))
sum = 0

begin = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10000):
        sum += arr[j * 10000 + i]
print(sum)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

The two versions' timings are almost identical (a difference of only ~3%). Am I missing something about the workings of the array?

Comment: This isn't C. Python has a *lot* of overhead, and that overhead is the same in both versions.

Comment: @user2357112 Do you mean that updating i and j, computing the index, and adding to the sum take some 97% of the runtime?

Comment: The array packs its values for memory efficiency, but its `__getitem__` method still returns a Python object, not the raw bytes from the array's memory allocation.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: No, stuff that you're not even thinking of takes most of the runtime. Allocating and deallocating millions of wrapper objects. Dynamic dispatch. The bytecode evaluation loop. Stuff like that.

Comment: @chepner You seem to mean that the compound assignment to `sum` is slow, because the added value is an integer object. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm simply saying there is a lot going on that could invalidate whatever assumptions you are making about how the CPU cache affects the execution time.

Comment: "*the sum take some 97% of the runtime?*" Actually, yes. In fact, even more: ≥99.7% on my machine. I expected Python to be slow, but not so much...

Answer (score 2):

The two codes are completely **dominated by the overhead of CPython** (by a very large margin). Let's try to understand why.

---

First of all, CPython is an **interpreter** so it optimize (nearly) nothing. This means operation like `i * 10000` are **recomputed** over and over while it can be precomputed in the parent loop. This also means instructions are fetch+decoded from a bytecode which is pretty slow (and cause many memory accesses + branches).

Additionally, access to global variable is significantly slower in CPython because the interpreter needs to fetch the variable from a global dictionary which is much slower than an access to the CPU cache.

Moreover, most CPython operations **allocate/free objects** and this is expensive (again, far much than a cache access). Indeed, allocating an object require to fetch a bucket data-structure and find some available space in it. Note that **small integers are cached** so they are not allocated. This means looping on small ranges is actually a bit faster. Checks for caching are always done so they add some overhead even when this is not possible to cache objets. Such operations requires several memory operations (twice since the free is needed). Not to mention the reference counting of each object also requiring memory operations (and the global interpreter lock operations).

In addition, CPython integer operation are pretty slow because CPython deals with variable-sized integers and not native one. This means CPython does additional checks when integers are large. Bad news: `sum` is a large integer.

The following code is actually about **2.5 times faster** than the original one and it **still spent a lot of time in CPython overheads** (lot of object allocation/free, ref-counting, C calls, etc.) :

```py
import array
import time
arr = array.array('l', range(100000000))

def compute(arr):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        tmp = i * 10000
        for j in range(100):
            tmp2 = tmp + j * 100
            for k in range(100):
                sum += arr[tmp2 + k]
    print(sum)

begin = time.time()
compute(arr)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

Pure-Python codes running with the CPython interpreter are so slow that you often cannot see the impact of caches. Thus, **using Python to benchmark such effect is a terrible idea**. The only way to see such an impact is to use **vectorized functions**, that is C function doing the job far more efficiently than an interpreted Python code. **Numpy** is able to do that. Here is an equivalent code for the two original codes:

```py
import numpy as np
import time
arr = np.arange(100_000_000).astype(np.int64)

begin = time.time()
sum = 0
for i in range(10000):
    sum += arr[i*10000:i*10000+10000].sum()
print(sum)
print(time.time() - begin)

begin = time.time()
sum = 0
for i in range(10000):
    sum += arr[i:100_000_000+i:10000].sum()
print(sum)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

The above code give the resulting timing:

```py
Original first code: 19.581 s
First Numpy code:     0.064 s
Second Numpy code:    0.725 s
```

The first Numpy code is about **300 times faster** than the original one showing how inefficient was the pure-Python code. Indeed, this shows that **≥99.7% of the original code was pure overheads**. We can also see that the second Numpy code is slower than the first due to the strided access pattern (but still 27 times faster than the first original code).

Nearly all the time is spent in the same section of the same internal function in Numpy for both variants. That being said, the second one is much slower because of the strided access. Here is the executed assembly code:

```
            Block 6:
0x180198970     add r9, qword ptr [rcx]
0x180198973     add rcx, r11
0x180198976     add r10, qword ptr [rcx]
0x180198979     add rcx, r11
0x18019897c     sub rdx, 0x1
0x180198980     jnz 0x180198970 <Block 6>
```

This code is not optimal when the array slice is contiguous. The compiler could have generated a significantly [SIMD code](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction_multiple_data) for this case. Not to mention, the the dependency chain prevent the processor to execute more instructions in parallel (on the same core). That being said, it enable us to see the impact of the strided access using the exact same assembly code. Thus, this is a pretty good benchmark unless you want to include the benefit of using SIMD instructions. SIMD instructions can make this code about 2-3 times faster on my machine. They can only speed up the non-strided use-case on mainstream platforms.

If you want to measure cache effects, it is generally better to use a **natively compiled code**. This can be done using Numba in Python (JIT compiler using LLVM) or simply natively compiled languages like C or C++.